# Axios call response to change data dynamically in pug front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, pug

I Have a search form and an endpoint that I am trying to get the restuls back so I can add a div inside my pug/jade file to let them know.  yes, order found.  or no, no order found.

Front end:

```
form#showCheckIn(method="POST" style="display:none;" action="/checkin" onsubmit="onCheckin()")
    div.form-group
        label(class='col-sm-2 control-label' style="width:auto;") Find
        input#checkin.form-control(name='checkin', autofocus=true placeholder="Phone, Order# or Email")
    div.form-group
            button#searchOrder.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Find
            i.fa.fa-search
```

Backend:

```
    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
      let checkin = req.body.checkin
    //orderEnd point
    let token = 'asdf
;      
      let primaryUrl = 'eventOrder/{eventID}/eventOrderCheckin?token='+token+'&accountLookup='+checkin;
    
      axios.post(primaryUrl)
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.data
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response.status === 404){
              //res.redirect('/errorCheckedIn')
              console.log('Order Not Found')
            }
            return Promise.reject(error.response);
            //console.log('ERROR',error);
          });
    
    });
```

Id like to be able to get the response from the axios call and pass it back to my front end so that I can display "order found" "no order found"

Ideas? or would making an ajax call here make more sense?

Comment: Could you show us the code of the endpoint that renders the page with a form? Also, would you please edit your code to be [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @macborowy ok, I separated it.  does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pug's conditional syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) to show order status after making `POST` request.

When user requests `/`, the application renders `search.pug` view without additional data, thus not showing order status message. On `POST` request, the application checks order status and pass it back to the `search` view to render.

Search view (`search.pug`):

```
form#showCheckIn(method="POST" action="/checkin")
  div.form-group
    label Find
    input(name='checkin', autofocus=true, placeholder="Phone, Order# or Email")
  div.form-group
    button(type="submit") Find
  if orderStatus
    div
      span Order #{orderStatus}
```

Application's backend:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => res.render('search'));

app.post('/checkin', (req, res, next) => {
    // Here you can make axios request for order status using form data.
    // For example purpose I simply set it to 'not found'.
    const orderStatus = 'not found';
    res.render('search', { orderStatus });
});
```